# Adding member to a group when registering them?

Tags: silverstripe

I have a registration form that allows a user to register. When they register I want to add them to a group automatically. I have tried using the `$member->AddToGroupByCode('Administrators')` method but this doesn't add any groups to the member.

What am I doing wrong?

**RegisterForm.php**

```
<?php

class RegisterForm extends Form {
    public function __construct($controller, $name) {
        $fields = new FieldList(
            TextField::create('FirstName'),
            TextField::create('Surname'),
            TextField::create('Email'),
            PasswordField::create('Password'),
            PasswordField::create('ConfirmPassword'),
            TextField::create('Username')

        );

        $actions = new FieldList(
            new FormAction('doRegister', 'Register')
        );

        $validator = new RequiredFields(
          'Email', 'Password', 'ConfirmPassword', 'Username'
        );

        parent::__construct($controller, $name, $fields, $actions, $validator);

        $this->disableSecurityToken();
    }

    public function doRegister($data, $form) {
        $member = new Member();
        $form->saveInto($member);
        $password = $data['Password'];
        $member->changePassword($password);
        $member->addToGroupByCode('Administrators') // Or could be another group I setup e.g 'Students' etc;
        $member->write();

        return $this->controller->redirect($this->controller->Link('thanks'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Try putting $member->addToGroupByCode('Administrators')  after $member->write();

Comment: @GavinBruce - Just tried that, and nope didn't work.

Comment: Try administrators rather than Administrators.

Comment: @GavinBruce - Nope didn't work either.

Answer (score 3):

Very simple. Just add this under your $member->write();

```
$member->Groups()->add($group);
```

And put above your $member->new Member();

```
$group = Group::get()->filter('Title','Client')->first();
```

Or

```
$group = Group::get()->filter('ID','SomeID')->first();
```

The $group is the target group that you want. You can filter it or get it by id.

Answer (score 1):

Member::addToGroupByCode($code, $title = "") uses internal Group code. When you create new group, the code is generated as lowercase title, but later the title can be changed. The only reliable way to get existing group codes are from the database.

```
SELECT Code, Title FROM `Group`;
```

If you called `$member->addToGroupByCode('administrators', 'Administrators');`
this would have created a new group with code 'administrators' if missing.

So the final code might be:

```
public function doRegister($data, $form) {
    $member = Member::get()->filter('Email', $data['Email'])->first();
    if ($member) {
        return $this->memberAlreadyExists();
    }

    $member = new Member();
    $member->update($data);
    $member->write();
    $member->addToGroupByCode('administrators', 'Administrators');

    return $this->controller->redirect($this->controller->Link('thanks'));
}
```

Comment: Hmm, tried your way of `$member->addToGroupByCode('administrators', 'Administrators');` - it worked for the first test I did but then every other person I tried to register after that no group was added... Strange behaviour hey.. I'm using SS 3.3.1

Comment: So on further testing I have found that if you create a group (can be called anything) and set its permissions to "Full administrative rights" in the CMS and then use a registration form like mine, it will only set that group once. Any other member that you register will not have a group added to it. However if you remove the "Full administrative rights" from the group it will add the group to the user for every user you register.. Possible bug? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

simple, you have to save the details before adding to a group.
just place

```
$member->addToGroupByCode('administrators', 'Administrators');
```

before

```
$member->write();
```