# SilverStripe add custom security Group

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

On SS 4.0.3 following [this guide](http://www.balbuss.com/adding-new-group-permissions/) and the [official doc](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/security/permissions/#permissionprovider), I successfully created a custom permission role.

Now I would create a custom group and add the default admin to it, as action performed by default in order to maintain those user/group/role settings either if the DB being dropped. I googled around many times but I didn't found any detailed tutorial to achieve this (using the `Group` class, the right place to implement this logic and so on).

Could anyone show me the way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to enforce a data structure you can use `DataObject::requireDefaultRecords`. See `Group::requireDefaultRecords` for an example of this, it runs on `dev/build` every time.

You will want to check whether the data you're creating exists before doing so though, to ensure you don't create the group every time.

Comment: Thanks @robbie, that was the way.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully setted up the panorama described on my question, thanks to @robbie and other sources that I combined all in one, in order to achieve my goal (I'll list them here below). I wanna share my approach to those could be face this logic in the future.

In the first place I created a brand new standard/global permission with `providePermissions()` in the `PageController` (see balbuss.com source).

Next, as @robbie suggested, I created a `Group` `DataExtension` in order to build up a new group and setted my previously created permission on it (see @Barry's solution source).

To add the default admin to this group, I had to create a new `Permission` `DataExtension` in which I assigned the group to the proper member (see @StefGuev suggestion source):

```
// Definizione Namespace
use SilverStripe\ORM\DataExtension;
use SilverStripe\Security\DefaultAdminService;
use SilverStripe\Security\Member;
use SilverStripe\Security\Group;

class PermessoExtension extends DataExtension
{
    /**
     * Metodo gestione inizializzazione records di default
     * Setter
     * @return void
     */
    public function requireDefaultRecords()
    {
        parent::requireDefaultRecords();

        $userAdmin = DefaultAdminService::getDefaultAdminUsername();
        $admin = Member::get()->filter('Email', $userAdmin)->first();
        $gruppo = Group::get()->filter('Code', 'negozianti')->first();

        // Controllo gruppo
        if (!$admin->inGroup($gruppo->ID)) {
            $admin->Groups()->add($gruppo);
            $admin->write();
        }
    }
}
```

I made this choice because during `dev/build`, `Permission` being built **after** `Member` table, so I could get the default admin without errors.

**Special thanks to these sources:**

[balbuss.com](http://www.balbuss.com/adding-new-group-permissions/)

[Bereusei's solution](https://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/general-questions/show/19005)

[Barry's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38614448)

[StefGuev suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41836865)